# Freebase MQL query is very slow when getting random record

Tags: freebase, mql

Because there is not a way to get a random record using MQL, I'm trying to get it by using a count first:

```
[{ "return": "count", "id": null, "name": null, "type": "/people/person"}]​
```

and by using a random page number `n` between `0` and `total / records per page`. In this example, there are more or less 2.000.000 records (40.000 pages with 50 records per page). 
Then I'm sending an envelope with a "page" property, and I'm also limiting the query to get 50 records in the nth page:

```
[{ "limit": 50, "id": null, "name": null, "type": "/people/person"}]​
```

In the Envelope:

```
{"page": n}
```

However, this query is very slow when `n > 50`. It is horribly slower when `n > 100`, and (for example) with `n > 2000` it doesn't even return.

Is there something I can do to get a random record? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this the database has to fetch all the earlier records so that it can count up to the one you want.  That's why it's so slow.  There are a couple of different things you could do:

1. Use the Freebase data dumps, either to generate a list of Freebase MIDs for random people which you then query via MQL or for your entire task (you don't say what information you are fetching)
2. Cast the randomization problem in a different form which is easier to compute.  For example, you might first pick a random creation time range for the topic (1997-now) and then pick a random person topic which was created during that time range.